# Receiving email in Parse via Mailgun

Tags: email, parse-platform, mailgun

So I'm new to Mailgun. I'm trying to use it to receive emails and forward them onto Parse so that I can save the information in them to a Parse database. I have a route set up correctly between Mailgun and Parse. Using the 'Send a sample POST' feature from Mailgun, data is added to my database in Parse. So my route is configured correctly from Mailgun to Parse.

### Problem

Sending an email to `sample-address@mydomain.com` gives me a bounced email back, with an **550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client** error. It also says that it's **not permitted to relay 550 through this server without authentication.** Seems like it's a problem with Mailgun not correctly configuring the mailserver. Maybe?

### Things I've Tried

- Checking all MX records, CNAME, TXT records - all are set up according to Mailgun's specs
- Not using a mydomain.com MX record - no change
- Using a different `address@mydomain.com`, or a `catchall` forwarder from Mailgun - no change in status

Anyone know what's up? It's a weird error that I can't figure out how to debug. Any tips on debugging this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd go through the process of setting up your domain again. Sounds like something is wonky in that area.

Comment: I'll add that in my experience, the send sample email didn't help me much. I found it more useful to simulate the post variables submitted to my listener. For that, I built my own test harness.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I did eventually just build a test suite with Parse that sent data to echo back data to Parse. Figured it out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I think your mail client is not allowing mailgun to post data, You can lower down the security parameters in your mail client settings, allowing less trusted systems to post.